# Getting error : cannot resolve method getResource()

Tags: java, android, share

I'm trying to share image with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` but getting this error:

> cannot resolve method getResource()

This is the code I'm trying to share image with:

```
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/myFolder");
            dir.mkdirs(); // build directory
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fileName = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
            File file = new File(dir, fileName);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();

            try {
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream is;
                Bitmap bitmap;
                is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image1);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                try {
                    is.close();
                    is = null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputFileUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share this image via"));
```

Comment: are you using Fragments

Comment: Is this an activity or a fragment if its a fragment then you will have to get Activity instance first to getResources

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are in a fragment use:

```
getActivity().getResources();
```

Or try:

```
getApplicationContext().getResources();
```

If you are in an Activity but in an inner class edit the word  `this` in this line:

```
is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

To:

```
is = Your_Activity_Class_Name.this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

First, the method is called [`getResources()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()), with an 's'. It is a method of the base [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. As such you have to access it from your Activity or Service. If your function belongs to a separate (non-Context) class you should either keep a reference to the context (bad practice) or use `getResources()` after your function has finished, in a callback, for example, in the context.

Answer (score 2):

If its an fragment this is what fix the issue for me:

```
getActivity.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

But if its an activity you can use:

```
this.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

And finally in an Adapter you can do:

```
getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.string_name);
```